# Limit of $t^2 \cos t x$ as distribution.

Tags: distribution-theory

I am interested in finding the limit $t^2 \cos t x$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ in the sense of schwartz distributions.

After some integration by parts I get

$$( t^2 \cos t x,\phi)=\int \cos(x)\phi(x/t)\frac{1}{t} \mathrm{d}x .$$

Can we from here conclude that the limit is zero by the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: This is btw a question in Hörmander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that you missed some derivatives on $\phi$ during your partial integration.

Furthermore, note $\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\left( -\frac{\sin(tx)}{t}\right) = t^2 \cdot \cos(tx)$ (i.e. use partial integration one more time). This leads to

$$\int t^2 \cdot \cos(tx) \cdot \phi(x) dx = \int \phi(x) \frac{d^3}{dx^3} \left(-\frac{\sin(tx)}{t}\right) dx = - (-1)^3 \int \phi'''(x) \cdot \frac{\sin(tx)}{t} dx.$$

Now note that the integrand is dominated by $\chi_{[-R,R]} \cdot \Vert \phi''' \Vert_{\sup} \in L^1$ for $t \geq 1$ (where $\rm{supp}(\phi) \subset [-R, R]$) and converges to zero pointwise.

Using dominated convergence, we conclude

$$\int t^2 \cdot \cos(tx) \cdot \phi(x) dx \xrightarrow[t \rightarrow \infty]{} 0.$$

In your integral, you can't really use dominated convergence, because for $t \rightarrow \infty$, the support of $\phi(x/t)$ will spread too much.

Comment: I've allowed myself to edit your post to increase readability.

Comment: Thanks! Is it good manner to edit my post (the derivatives) now so that the question makes more sense for hypothetical  readers?